# SQL Property differences between tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Background: I have 2 tables (an old table from years ago, and a new table with mapped properties, and additional properties that will be filled in by the new system operator). The 'old' properties are mapped to the 'new' properties one-to-one and they have been copied over via another tool.

I would like to compare the 2 tables' properties and verify that everything was converted properly to the new table. I understand how to find items that are missing from the NEW_Table, but not the actual properties, especially if there are 2 differences on the same row (My real tables have about 30 properties):

```
OLD_Table Properties      NEW_Table Properties
VARCHAR2 UID              VARCHAR2 UID
INTEGER Num               INTEGER Count
VARCHAR2 Name             VARCHAR2 Title
```

```
OLD_Table Data            NEW_Table Data
UID  Num  NameA           UID  Count Title
---  ---  ----            ---  ----- -----
01   30   Test            01   30    <null>
02   66   Another         02   44    SomethingElse
03   22   Fun             03   10    Fun
```

I would like this output

```
UID |OLD Property Name|OLD_Table Val|NEW_Table Val
----+-----------------+-------------+-------------
01  |NameA            |Test         |null
02  |Num              |66           |44
02  |NameA            |Another      |SomethingElse
03  |Num              |22           |10
```

Is this possible? I can currently get rows that "one or more properties" don't match using a simple A=B and C=D, but I can't figure out how to get the property name, or multiple different property values from the same record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need UNION ALL because you must check 2 columns:

```
select 
  o."UID", 'Num' "OLD Property Name", to_char(o.Num) "OLD_Table Val", to_char(n."Count") "NEW_Table Val" 
from old_table o 
inner join new_table n 
on n."UID" = o."UID" 
and ((n."Count" <> o.Num) or (n."Count" is null and o.Num is not null) or (n."Count" is not null and o.Num is null))
union all
select 
  o."UID", 'NameA' "OLD Property Name", o.NameA "OLD_Table Val", n.Title "NEW_Table Val" 
from old_table o 
inner join new_table n 
on n."UID" = o."UID" 
and ((n.Title <> o.NameA) or (n.Title is null and o.NameA is not null) or (n.Title is not null and o.NameA is null))
order by "UID"
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=11c3bbddab28263e1e1503ac84e067ec).
Results:

```
> UID | OLD Property Name | OLD_Table Val | NEW_Table Val
> :-- | :---------------- | :------------ | :------------
> 01  | NameA             | Test          | null         
> 02  | Num               | 66            | 44           
> 02  | NameA             | Another       | SomethingElse
> 03  | Num               | 22            | 10
```

Comment: I have 30+ columns. Theres no way to do this without having 30 UNION ALLs?

Comment: Thanks for the db-fiddle link as well! This tool will definately help with all SQL tasks!

Comment: You want 1 row in the results for each pair of columns that are different, so you have to use UNION.

Comment: Thats what I was afraid of as well. There are about 15 tables to join to get to the data I need to get to. This query will take quite some time :
(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL` and `inequalities`(`n."Count" != o.Num` and nvl(`n.Title,' ') != o.NameA`) together :

```
with old_tab("UID",Num,NameA) as
(
 select '01',30,'Test'    from dual union all
 select '02',66,'Another' from dual union all
 select '03',22,'Fun'     from dual 
), new_tab("UID","Count",Title) as 
(
 select '01',30, null           from dual union all
 select '02',44,'SomethingElse' from dual union all
 select '03',10,'Fun'           from dual
)
select o."UID", 'NameA' "Old Table Name", o.NameA as "Old Table Value", 
       n.Title as "New Table Value"   
 from old_tab o
 join new_tab n 
   on  nvl(n.Title,' ') != o.NameA
   and n."UID" = o."UID"
union all
select o."UID", 'Num' "Old Table Name", to_char(o.Num), to_char(n."Count")
  from old_tab o
  join new_tab n 
   on  n."Count" != o.Num
   and n."UID" = o."UID";
```

P.S: `Count` and `UID` are reserved keywords in Oracle Database, So please do not prefer such words for naming.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b27e1cd1498d122f5ae2e7438a33b7f6)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `connect by level` and `case when` on level as following:

```
Select uid, 
old_property_name,
old_table_val, 
new_table_val
From

(Select o.uid,

Case 
when level = 1 then
'Num' 
When level = 2 then
'NameA'
end as old_property_name,

Case 
when level = 1 then
O.num
When level = 2 then
O.NameA
end as old_table_val,

Case 
when level = 1 then
N.count
When level = 2 then
N.title
end as new_table_val

From old_table o
Join new_table n
On (o.uid = n.uid)
Connect by level <= 2)
Where old_table_val <> new_table_val;
```

Here 2 levels are used as per sample data. In your case if there are 30 column changes need to be tracked, you will need to use 30 level.

I have done `INNER JOIN` considering that there are all records available in both the tables.

**Note**: I have given this answer from mobile as I am travelling, please correct the typo mistakes in query, if any.

Cheers!!